# "No such method" and "Parse error in application web.xml". while running maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am developing a spring-rest application in Eclipse IDE. While running the application as maven-build i am getting errors showing "no such method" and "parse error in application web.xml"

Error shown in console:

```
  SEVERE: End event threw exception
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:849)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)


  Mar 25, 2015 10:56:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
  SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/home   /vittisysadmin/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/web.xml
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/vittisysadmin/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/web.xml; lineNumber: 109; columnNumber: 15; Error at (109, 15) :    org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
at  org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2711)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2743)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1066)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)

  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:849)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
... 26 more
```

My pom.xml file is:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.oreilly.springdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-book</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spring-data-book-rest</artifactId>

    <name>Spring Data Book - REST exporter</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data REST -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.0.RC2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

My web.xml file:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


  **<servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>**



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>





    <!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mapping for the SSI servlet -->


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>scurl</extension>
        <mime-type>text/vnd.curl.scurl</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sda</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.stardivision.draw</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sdc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.stardivision.calc</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sdd</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.stardivision.impress</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sdkd</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.solent.sdkm+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sdkm</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.solent.sdkm+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sdp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/sdp</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sdw</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.stardivision.writer</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>see</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.seemail</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>seed</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.fdsn.seed</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sema</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.sema</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>semd</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.semd</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>semf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.semf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ser</extension>
        <mime-type>application/java-serialized-object</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>setpay</extension>
        <mime-type>application/set-payment-initiation</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>setreg</extension>
        <mime-type>application/set-registration-initiation</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>sfd-hdstx</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.hydrostatix.sof-data</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>


    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- Compiled WML Script -->
        <extension>wmlsc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wmv</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-ms-wmv</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wmx</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-ms-wmx</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wmz</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-msmetafile</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wpd</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.wordperfect</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wpl</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-wpl</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wps</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-works</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wqd</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.wqd</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>


    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xpw</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.intercon.formnet</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xpx</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.intercon.formnet</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xsl</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xslt</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xslt+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xsm</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.syncml+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xspf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xspf+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xul</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xvm</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xv+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xvml</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xv+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xwd</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-xwindowdump</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xyz</extension>
        <mime-type>chemical/x-xyz</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xz</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-xz</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>yang</extension>
        <mime-type>application/yang</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>yin</extension>
        <mime-type>application/yin+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-compress</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>Z</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-compress</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z1</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z3</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z4</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z5</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z6</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z7</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z8</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-zmachine</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zaz</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.zzazz.deck+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zip</extension>
        <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zir</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.zul</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zirz</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.zul</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zmm</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.handheld-entertainment+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

can anyone please help me in solving the issue.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show your web.xml

Comment: Ashok can you paste apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/web.xml file

Comment: @Thanks for replay . i will copy my web.xml file also

Comment: @Kick i edited my post by adding web.xml file. I deleted some of <mime-mapping> tags. because the file is too long to post.

Comment: @Ashokkumar can you highlight the lineNumber:109 at file apache-tomcat-7.0.57/conf/web.xml

Comment: @Kick line number 109 is having </servlet>.  i kept that code between ** 109 line code part **

Comment: @Ashokkumar how are you resolving the dependency of Apache Tomcat catalane org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet ?